# How to configure Nuxtjs from Authentication in Azure B2C?

Tags: nuxt.js, azure-ad-b2c, auth0

I would like to know if you can help me with information or an example of how to correctly implement the nuxt auth0 and the Azure B2C, since I tried to configure it but azure returns a code, which I do not know how to return it through the auth of nuxtjs.

I show a fragment of my middleware with which I can login and return the code to generate the access_token, but not through the nuxt auth.

```js
import querystring from 'query-string'
import axios from 'axios'
export default async function (req, res, next) {
  
  const query = querystring.parse(req.url.split('?')[1])
  const Code = query.code
  const data = {
    grant_type: process.env.GRANT_TYPE,
    code: Code,
    redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
    client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    scope: process.env.SCOPE
  }
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      process.env.TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
      querystring.stringify(data),
      {
        headers:
        {
          'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      })
    
  } catch (error) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(error.response.data)
  }
  next()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auth0 is provider specific. Instead use the [OpenIDConnect](https://dev.auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/openIDConnect) and [OAuth2](https://dev.auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/oauth2) schemes.

Alternatively, you may try adding [vue-msal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-msal) which wraps [Microsoft Authentication Library for JavaScript (MSAL.js)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js#readme) and natively supports Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Thanks.
I am trying with MSAL and everything seems to be working fine.